# How many ways to distribute balls so that at least $4$ red balls are selected? at most $3$ red balls are selected?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm trying to figure out the following:
A bowl contains balls with eight different colors, one of which is red.  Assuming there are at least $20$ balls of each color, how many ways can a total of $20$ balls be distributed among the eight different colors if

(1) the bowl must contain at least four red balls?

(2) must contain at most $3$ red balls?

For (1), I got $245,157$. Is this correct? 
$(16 + 8 - 1)C16$

Also, any clues or hints to solve the second part would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the first sentence supposed to read "A bowl contains balls with eight different colors, one of which is red."?

Answer (score 2):

$(1)$ looks correct.

**Hint:** "at most 3 red balls" = "all distributions" - "at least 4 red balls".

Possibly, attention needs to be paid when counting "all distributions", since the wording "one of which is red" might be interpreted as "at least 1 red".

Comment: The phrase "one of which is red" refers to the colors of the balls in the bowl from which the balls are drawn.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, that is how I would interpret it, but the whole sentence is awkward: "A bowl contains eight balls with different colors, one of which is red." so "one of which" could also refer to balls, not colors. If we wrote it properly as: "A bowl contains *balls with eight different colors*, one of which is red." it's much clearer that "one of which" refers to colors. That's why I said "possibly", since we don't have the original wording of the exercise.

Comment: Upon rereading the question, I suspect it meant to say a bowl contains balls with eight different colors, one of which is red.  Otherwise, the following sentence makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you both for responding! It does mean "A bowl contains balls with eight different colors, one of which is red." I just got clarification.

Comment: @Ennar does that mean we add up 4 probabilities (0 to 3)?

Comment: @Val, $A = \{ \text {distributions with at least 4 red balls} \}$ and $U = \{ \text{all distributions} \}$, then $U\setminus A = \{ \text {distributions with at most 3 red balls} \}$, and obviously $|U\setminus A| = |U| - |A|$. Or simply put, any distribution has either *3 or less red balls* or *4 or more red balls*, but not both. These sets are complements of each other.

Comment: Edit: If I did it correctly, is it 116,280?

Comment: @Val, no, it should be $_{27}C_{7}- _{23}C_{7}=642873$.

Comment: @Ennar I was way off! Makes sense, thank you again!!